# When creating a composer package, what "Package Type" should I choose

Tags: php, package, composer-php, packagist

I'm creating my first PHP Composer package (following [these instructions](http://blog.jgrossi.com/2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package/)).
I've run

```
$ composer init
```

and am filling in the details, it is now asking me for

> Package Type (e.g. library, project, metapackage, composer-plugin) []:

I assume this is just a human-decipherable label for categorising the different packages?

I wondered if there is a definition of package types somewhere?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found this as posting the question :

> #### Composer Package Types
>
> Out of the box, Composer supports four types:
>
> - **library**: This is the default. It will simply copy the files to /vendor.
> - **project**: This denotes a project rather than a library. For example application shells like the Symfony standard edition, CMSs
>     like the SilverStripe installer or full fledged applications
>     distributed as packages.
> - **metapackage**: An empty package that contains requirements and will trigger their installation, but contains no files and will not
>     write anything to the filesystem.
> - **composer-plugin**: A package of type composer-plugin may provide an installer for other packages that have a custom type. Only use a custom type if you need custom logic
>     during installation.
>
> *Package types are used for custom installation logic. If you have a package that needs some special logic, you can define a custom type.
>   This could be a symfony-bundle, a wordpress-plugin or a
>   typo3-cms-extension. These types will all be specific to certain
>   projects, and they will need to provide an installer capable of
>   installing packages of that type.*

Source : https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md

Comment: Just remembering that `composer-plugin` type are installed first, so if you plan to have a package of composer patches for the third-party packages you use, it becomes pretty useful